# Is it possible to configure custom plugin directories for Zend?

Tags: zend-framework, plugins, directory

I want to be able to store custom plugins in the library folder of my application (currently I am storing them in the Zend library itself). Is there a way of providing additional plugin directories in the application.ini file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this one out:

Create a folder in:

```
 application/library/PREFIX
```

(where PREFIX is the class prefix for your plugin, and it's root directory)

In the application.ini file - add:

```
 autoloaderNamespaces[] = "PREFIX"
```

add this line to register the plugin with the Front Controller

```
 resources.frontController.plugins.PluginName= "PREFIX_PluginName"
```

If you need/want to organise your plugin folders - use the Zend underscore = directories naming convention - so this:

```
resources.frontController.plugins.PluginName= "PREFIX_Path_To_Folder_PluginName"
```

would refer to a class called:

```
PREFIX_Path_To_Folder_PluginName
```

in a file called: "PluginName.php"

in directory:

```
application/library/PREFIX/Path/To/Folder/PluginName.php
```

Hope that helps anyone who needs to ask this question